# How can the maximum value of $f(\theta) = 5\cos\theta + 3\cos(\theta + \pi /3)$ be $10$?

Tags: trigonometry

My book states that the maximum value of $f(\theta)=5\cos\theta + 3\cos( \theta + \pi /3) $ is $10$.

If I think, no value of  $\theta $ exists for which $\cos\theta $ is more than $1$. So how can the maximum value of the above function be $10$? At least I think it should have a maximum value of less than $8$.

heres the solution from my book - 
[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRx3y.jpg): https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSmK1.jpg here's the question :-[image]

Comment: I agree with you.

Comment: You mean $$f(\theta)= 5\cos\theta+3\cos(\theta+\pi/3)$$?

Comment: Yeah I would say that definitely
$$
5\underbrace{\cos{\theta}}_{\leq 1} + 3\underbrace{\cos{\left(\theta + \frac{\theta}{3} \right)}}_{\leq 1} \leq 5+3 = 8
$$

Comment: Also you can use
$$
\cos{\left(\theta + \frac{\pi}{3} \right)} = \cos{\theta}\cos{\frac{\pi}{3}} - \sin{\theta}\sin{\frac{\pi}{3}}
$$

Comment: If I were you, I would type out the solution in the book here. I'm suspecting that there's a mistake somewhere. Either in the book or in the interpretation of the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The book is not saying that the maximum value is $10$, it's only saying the maximum value is *no greater than* $10$. Similarly, the *minimum* isn't necessarily $-4$, it's just no less than that.

However, as the OP points out in comments (and I should have seen for myself), the solution is bounding not $5\cos\theta+3\cos(\theta+\pi/3)$, but $5\cos\theta+3\cos(\theta+\pi/3)+3$.  The "easy" bounds there are $5+3+3=11$ and $-5-3+3=-5$, so $10$ and $-4$ are definitely better. It appears the book simply neglected to include the additional $+3$ in the problem statement.

Added later: Actually, $10$ and $-4$ *are* the max and min values.  In general, any expression of the form $a\cos\theta+b\sin\theta$ has $\pm\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ as its exact max and min. I should have noticed this as well.

Comment: Oh sorry there's a printing mistake in my book in stating the question they should've added +3.

Answer (score 2):

To get the true extremal values you could also differentiate $f(\theta)$ and find the values of $\theta$ where $f'(\theta)=0$, and then plug these values back into $f(\theta)$.

Comment: That's a fun exercise to find by hand. I got an absolute maximum of $$f\left( \tan^{-1}\left(\frac{-3\sqrt{3}}{13}\right)\right)=7$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $f( \theta) \le 5+3=8<10$ for all $\theta$.

Comment: Isn't the pi/3 part of the cosine's argument?